# How to focus a div which has role of textbox?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, focus, role

```
<div id="mainEditor" role="textbox" class="postArticle-content" contenteditable="true">
```

I have this div control and I want this div to ready to write once page is loaded.
But $("#mainEditor").focus() doesn't work.

How can I focus it?

js code;

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(window).load(function () {
    $("#mainEditor").focus();
}); });
```

Comment: please post the code where you given $("#mainEditor").focus()

Comment: I have updated the question.. @Anoop LL

Comment: You can't focus on a `div` (I don't think). Do you really mean `focus`, or just bring into the visible area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that load function inside ready..

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$("#mainEditor").focus();
```

});

This will do the job

Comment: Yes, like the answer I gave already. But it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why accept this? Are you guys buddies or something??

Comment: @bukko what is the issue?

Comment: @bukko buddies?? why ?? you think this wont work?? you think cant focus on div?? right?? https://jsfiddle.net/0hmgm6eb/ this is for you

Comment: Theres a few: (1) you can't focus on a `div` (2) I already gave the same answer, but I explained why it won't work.

Comment: That will work .. you can focus.. you just saw only the div tag.. just look at the other attributes.. open the link that will solve your doubts

Comment: Buddies because I answered first. However, I accept that your answer would also work (I didn't know you could do that).

Comment: that you need to ask that guy why he selected my answer.. may be you have given a wrong info.. "focusing div make no sense.."

Comment: Either way, clearly there is a massive hole in my HTML skills that needs addressing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#mainEditor").focus();

});
```

Or, if you want to use your `textbox` role

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("div[role=textbox]").focus();

});
```

But - why would you try to give the focus to a div?

This only makes sense with an anchor `<a>..</a>` or a control the user can change, like a text input field `<input... />`